# Find and delete duplicate entries in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 60 columns in it. I would like to delete duplicate entries. It has to compare all 60 columns for a record to be considered duplicate. 
I tried setting all 60 columns to UNIQUE in MySQL, but I get this error

```
#1070 - Too many key parts specified; max 16 parts allowed
```

Any other solutions out there?

Comment: Do you mean all 60 columns should be considered to mark a record as duplicate?

Comment: Please show your table schema and how you set the `UNIQUE` index. Looks like you're doing something completely wrong.

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant to say columns, not rows.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about the use of the table. Why are 60 unique columns needed? Just to know a bit more about the background. Maybe you should just [**normalize**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your table and bring it to the 3rd normal form if possible?

Comment: Do you want to delete the rows as a one-time job or is this question about a table schema with `UNIQUE` constraints?

Comment: I'm exporting data from a database to a MySQL database. Problem is that there supposed to be one unique column, but there are duplicate entries. It'd be easy to just delete the data based on that one specific column but in some cases I need to combine data from the two entries. So first, I want to get rid of the duplicate entries that got no additional data. This is a one time job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your new table should have the exact same schema than the old one

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
```

To `INSERT` all distinct rows into `new_table` use

```
INSERT INTO new_table
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM old_table;
```

Then you can `DROP TABLE old_table` and `RENAME TABLE new_table TO old_table` or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest try something like this

Select col1, ..., col60 from [mytable] group by col1,...col60 HAVING count(*)>1

this will list all the duplicate rows. Once you have that you can delete the duplicate rows.

Comment: I don't think that's working. MySQL returns all entries.